# Is it possible to use WSDL in org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition?

Tags: xsd, wsdl, spring-ws

I am trying to set up SOAP on Spring WS and now i configure Spring beans with file like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
           xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"  
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services  
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd  
                                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
                                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  
       <context:component-scan base-package="com.blog.samples.services" />  
       <sws:annotation-driven />  
       <!--  
            Our test service bean  
       -->  
       <bean id="AccountDetailsService" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition" lazy-init="true">  
      <property name="schemaCollection">  
        <bean class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">  
          <property name="inline" value="true" />  
          <property name="xsds">  
            <list>  
              <value>schemas/AccountDetailsServiceOperations.xsd</value>  
            </list>  
          </property>  
        </bean>  
      </property>  
      <property name="portTypeName" value="AccountDetailsService"/>  
      <property name="serviceName" value="AccountDetailsServices" />  
      <property name="locationUri" value="/endpoints"/>  
    </bean>  
  </beans>
```

Unfortunatly i have not xsd, i have only wsdl which described my service. The question is : may i use somehow my wsdl in this spring configuration file? If yes - how (use wsdl instead of wsdl)? I know that i can extract xsd from wsdl, but would like to use only wsdl.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could use SimpleWsdl11Definition instead of DefaultWsdl11Definition:

Via XML:

```
<sws:static-wsdl id="operations" location="[your_location]/[your_wsdl].wsdl"/>
```

Via Java config:

```
@Bean(name = "operations")
public SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition() {
    SimpleWsdl11Definition s = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
    s.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("[your_location]/[your_wsdl].wsdl"));
    return s;
}
```

"id" respectively bean-name is the identifier on how your .wsdl can be accessed. In the case above:

```
http://[your_server]/[url_mapping_from_message_dispatcher]/operations.wsdl
```

Comment: Is there any way to override `soap:address location` with SimpleWsdl11Definition?

Tip: if your wsdl should response with URL containing `?wsdl` at the query string you can achieve this via filter (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4215351/2352256).